# Web.Services SoapException Illegal use of this web service

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, protocols

I am using webservice to get an OrderHistory. It is working fine on my local pc and also on my OLD server. Now, we have moved web service to the NEW server and there it is not working. Getting below error.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException' occurred in System.Web.Services.dll

Additional information: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: *** Illegal use of this web service !!! ***

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: *** Illegal use of this web service !!! ***
```

at WSElectronicOrder.WSElectronicOrder.GetOrderHistory(String Key, String FullAccountNo, String PONumber, String FromDate, String ToDate)

What is the possible cause of this problem? are there any setting do I need to do on server? Do I need to give any permission?

Thanks

Comment: Almost certainly, but you have documentation from when you set it up before, and given you have it working on 2 machines you should be able to debug what is going wrong

Comment: `Illegal use of this web service !!!` seems like a custom Exception, could you share the code with us?